# Anyone else find Winter 16 the Napili Community template initial load to be slow?

Tags: community, community-builder

I've been playing with the Winter 16 updates to Communities. Is it just me or is the first load of the Community very slow? I'm seeing 20-30 seconds before any visual feedback.

This is without doing any changes to the standard template - in a Dev org, create a new Community, select Napili, make sure it's visible to the public, then open up an Incognito window and hit the Community's URL, with the browser's dev tools open. Take a look at the Network tab to get an idea of what's going on. When profiling, a lot of the time is spent in "idle" rather than any scripts running.

Would appreciate anybody else's observations!